# Что интересное или что интересного? Родительный падеж после «что»

Tags: склонение, прилагательные

Интересует такой вопрос, на который не могу найти ответ. Чем обуславливается употребление именительного или родительного падежа прилагательного после местоимения «что»? Например, в таких примерах:

Что хорошее/хорошего сделал этот человек?
Что интересное/интересного ты расскажешь?

Понимаю, что здесь можно заменить «что» на условно разговорное «чего», но тем не менее вопрос остаётся открытым. Даже не знаю как гуглить правило, потому что в поиске ключевое «что» вообще теряется.

Answer (score 3):

Речь идет об устойчивой конструкции (фразеосхеме): сочетании слова "что" с родительным падежом субстантивированного прилагательного: "что нового", "что хорошего", "что плохого" и т.п.

> ...Что интересного в чужом письме? (Гончаров)
>
> ...он никак не мог понять, что хорошего в человеке, если он не годится
>   в лыцари (Белинский)

Обуславливается такое употребление исключительно традицией, так как вне такой конструкции прилагательное склоняется: "чего хорошего", "чему хорошему", "о чем хорошем". Скорее всего, исторически применение родительного падежа связано с его употреблением с числительными "много", "мало" в подобных конструкциях:

> Что хорошего в этом человеке? В нем много хорошего и мало плохого.

Как видите, во втором предложении другой падеж невозможен. Другой вероятной причиной появления конструкции с родительным падежом может быть то, что слово "что" в 18-19 веках употреблялось также в значении "сколько", "много ли":

> «Что стоит эта шляпка и косынка?» ― спросила она у торговки.  «Шестьдесят рублей...» (Крылов)

Answer (score 0):

Простое объяснение можно получить, если представить себе это выражение как сокращение *точно* такого же по смыслу, но более развернутого и формального, с твердым родительным падежом, обусловленным предлогом:

> Что ***из*** того, что принято считать хорошим [что мы с вами называем
>   хорошим], сделал этот человек?
>
> Здесь: "то, что принято считать хорошим" = "хорошее".
>
> В родительном падеже: что (из) хорошего?

Дальнейшее упрощение связано с упусканием предлога при сохранении падежа. В примере "что интересного" можно рассуждать аналогично:

> Что интересного [= что из интересного  (***из*** того, что тебе
>   представляется интересным )] ты расскажешь?